# Change height of a custom actionbar using java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am stuck in an issue. I'm a junior android developer. I want to change the height of my custom action bar on a click event. But I'm not able to find a way 
how to change actionbar's height. I saw other related posts, but didnt find exactly what I need. 
I want to toggle a hidden layout part of action bar, upon click event. The height of action should fit to the content size each time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="5" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.69"
            android:src="@drawable/header_image" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:contentDescription="Seperator"
            android:src="@drawable/header_seperator" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_show_searchbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:contentDescription="search"
            android:src="@drawable/header_search" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_hidesearchbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:contentDescription="search"
            android:src="@drawable/header_search_active"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:contentDescription="Seperator"
            android:src="@drawable/header_seperator" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_header_navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:contentDescription="navigation"
            android:src="@drawable/header_navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:visibility="gone" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/fields"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Keyword"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.0"
            android:background="@drawable/header_language"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

On a click event, i want to toggle the second inner linear layout. Is It possible? or should i use fragments in activity?

Comment: What you using? ToolBar or What?

Comment: Show us some code to work upon.

Comment: Ok, I'm updating my answer with code

Comment: What do you mean by "*toggle the second inner linear layout*"? You want to increase the height of  the first LinearLayout and decrease the height of the second one?

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is that you want make the 2nd LinearLayout (the one that has visibility:"gone") be visible on a click event. You have first to set an id for that layout and do something like this:

```
LinearLayout yourLinearLayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayoutId);
```

and inside your click event

```
yourLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

that will make your layout appear and because the father has layout_height="wrap_content" it will fit to the size of the child when it is visible.